# CheckboxChanged event not firing in GridView on checkbox uncheck- Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a Checkbox in the grid view and I am having a OnCheckedChange event. This event is fired on Check and also if there are multiple rows in the Grid. But **when there is only one row the OnCheckedChanged event is fired on checking the checkbox but not on Unchecking the checkbox**. I am trying to resolve this issue. But so far nothing good has happened. **This is a WebApplication not a Windows Forms application. So I am not able to uses CellValueChanged Event**. Following is my code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridHeaderStyle" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridRowStyle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectEmployee" runat="server" key="chkEmployeeSrcItem" index='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container, "RowIndex") %>' pair='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectEmployee_CheckedChanged" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void gvEmployeeSource_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Code Goes here
    }
}

protected void chkSelectEmployee_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Code goes here
}
```

Comment: @PaulZahra My project is Web Application. Not windows form application. so I wont be able to use the namespace System.Windows.Forms

Comment: @PaulZahra This is not a duplicate question

Comment: Are you binding to the grid in page load?

Comment: Yes. I am binding the grid in Pageload

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, taken from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/2003636.aspx?check%20box%20inside%20gridview%20is%20not%20firing%20event%20when%20it%20is%20unchecked):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="id" AutoPostBack="true"  OnCheckedChanged="id_CheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then server side code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    // Get data from datasource and bind it to the gridview.
}

protected void id_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox lnkView = (sender as CheckBox);

    if (lnkView.Checked)
    {
         Response.Write( "you checked the checkbox");
    }
    else if (!lnkView.Checked)
    {
         Response.Write("checkbox is not checked");
    }
}
```